# Idiomatic ruby for generating permutations?

Tags: ruby, recursion, idioms

I'm wondering what the idiomatic version of this function for generating permutations would look like in Ruby. I understand that `[1,2,3].permutation.to_a` will generate the same result, but I'm more interested in learning Ruby and how to approach a recursive problem like this in Ruby.

```
def permutations(seq)
    if seq.empty? || seq.count == 1
        seq
    else
        seq.map { |x|
            permutations(seq.select { |e| e != x }).map { |p|
                if p.class == Fixnum
                    [x, p]
                else
                    p.unshift(x)
                end
            }
        }.flatten(1)
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could simplify that `if` into `case (p)` and `when Fixnum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Array
  def permutations
    return [self] if size < 2
    perm = []
    each { |e| (self - [e]).permutations.each { |p| perm << ([e] + p) } }
    perm
  end
end 

[1, 2, 3].permutations #=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Source: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/32844

Edit: To avoid monkey-patching, put it into a module:

```
module ArrayExtensions
  def permutations
    #snip
  end
end

Array.send :include, ArrayExtensions
```

Comment: Very nice and concise. In general, is this the ruby way-- to add behavior to a object when such behavior doesn't exist? The example from the url (fascinating!) was drawn from the small talk world.

Comment: Yep - if the method is only going to be used on a single class, I'd put it in that class. Otherwise you'll unnecessarily be cluttering your code with `if x.is_a? Array` etc.

Comment: drsnyder: Its called monkey patching, here is a great blogpost about it http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/monkeypatching-for-humans.html

Comment: @drsnyder: another way of doing it without modifying core classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12864516/1004889

Comment: If you want to avoid monkey-patching, a cleaner way to do it would be to put it into a module then use `.send :include`, see edit.

Comment: @AlexPeattie: I'm blown away that you think that's significantly different (even cleaner!).

Comment: @pje I meant cleaner than monkey-patching (the original code I'd posted), not cleaner than your solution, which is equally valid.

Comment: @AlexPeattie: `Array.send(:include, ArrayExtensions)` just adds all of the methods in your `ArrayExtensions` module as instance methods in the class `Array`. I meant that, since both versions of your answer add methods to `Array`, they're not significantly different. (They're both "monkey patching" `Array`).

Comment: Monkey-patching refers to directly modifying the methods in a class - whereas putting them into a mixin (http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html#S2) isn't monkey-patching. From the article you linked: "Needless - another technique (such as a mixin, or locally extending individual objects) would have worked as well or better.". I completely agree that the difference is subtle, but using mixin is less dangerous than monkey patching directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common in Ruby (esp. Rails) to add functionality like this directly to the core class.

One alternative to that approach would be a separate, static utility module:

```
module ArrayUtils
  def self.permute(array)
    return [array] if array.size < 2

    array.flat_map do |elem|
      permute(array - [elem]).map do |perm|
        ([elem] + perm)
      end
    end
  end
end

ArrayUtils.permute [1, 2, 3]
# => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```